# How to chain the use of maybe argument in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to build a string from optional arguments. For example to generate a greeting string from a title and a name This is trivial in a imperative language and would look like this

```
def greeting(title, name):
   s = "Hello"
   if a :
        s += "Mr"
   if b: 
        s += b
```

My first attempt in haskell is :

```
greeting :: Bool-> Maybe String -> String
greeting title name = foldl (++) "Hello" (catMaybes [title' title, name])
   where
   title' True = Just "Mr"
   title' False = Nothing
```

I'm sure there is a bette way to do it. First, I'm sure this `foldl` `catMaybes` combination exists somewhere but I couldn't find it. Second, folding works here because I'm using the same operation (and the same type). So what is there a better way to do it ?
I was also thinking using a Writer but I'm not sure either how to do it.

### Update

This is only an example (maybe bad or too simple). My question is more , how to generalize it to many arguments .

So the real problem is not just about concatening 2 strings but more how to generate letters from a template with optional sections and parameters, like you would do in *Word* with the mail merge tool.

You have on one a csv file with customer name, telephone number, how much is overdue  etc. Some of the field could be optional. On the other side you have a *template* and the goal is to generate one letter per customer (row) according to the *template. The question is then how do you write this *template* in haskell (without the help of any templating library).
In my first example the template will be "hello (Mr){name}" but in the real word the template could be in invoice, a statement letter or even a complete accounting report.

Comment: You haven't specified what `options` is.

Comment: Does `greeting True Nothing` make sense as an invocation (it would produce `Hello Mr`, assuming you mean to add a space between the two words)?

Comment: @Jeffrey: It doesn't but it doesn't really matter. It's just an example. Maybe I should have choosen a more abstract example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell is so good at abstractions, it can easily replicate the imperative patterns. What you're doing in your example is called a "builder" pattern. `Writer` is a monad, which wraps a pattern of accumulation or "building" of any `Monoid` data, and `String` is a `Monoid`.

```
import Control.Monad.Writer hiding (forM_)
import Data.Foldable

greeting :: Bool -> Maybe String -> String -> String
greeting mr name surname = 
  execWriter $ do
    tell $ "Hello,"
    when mr $ tell $ " Mr."
    forM_ name $ \s -> tell $ " " ++ s
    tell $ " " ++ surname
    tell $ "!"

main = do
  putStrLn $ greeting False (Just "Ray") "Charles"
  putStrLn $ greeting True Nothing "Bean"
```

Outputs:

```
Hello, Ray Charles!
Hello, Mr. Bean!
```

Comment: that's the `forM` I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

Actually Haskell is smarter than any imperative approach.

Let's imagine `name` has a value `Nothing`. Does it make sense to render something like `"Hello Mr"`? Probably it would make more sense to consider it as an exceptional situation, and for that we can again use `Maybe`. So first of all, I'd update the signature of the function to the following:

```
greeting :: Bool -> Maybe String -> Maybe String
```

Now we can look at our problem again and find out that Haskell provides multiple ways to approach it.

### Hello, Monads

`Maybe` is a monad, so we can use the `do` syntax with it:

```
greeting mr name = do
  nameValue <- name
  return $ if mr
    then "Hello, Mr. " ++ nameValue
    else "Hello, " ++ nameValue
```

### Hello, Functors

`Maybe` is also a functor, so alternatively we can use `fmap`:

```
greeting mr name = 
  if mr
    then fmap ("Hello, Mr. " ++) name
    else fmap ("Hello, " ++) name
```

We can also do a bit of refactoring, if we consider the signature as the following:

```
greeting :: Bool -> (Maybe String -> Maybe String)
```

i.e., as a function of one argument, which returns another function. So the implementaion:

```
greeting mr = 
  if mr
    then fmap ("Hello, Mr. " ++)
    else fmap ("Hello, " ++)
```

or

```
greeting True  = fmap ("Hello, Mr. " ++)
greeting False = fmap ("Hello " ++)
```

if you find this syntax better.

Comment: "Actually Haskell is smarter than any imperative approach." He says it how it is! (Although Haskell is the finest imperative language.)

Comment: Thanks for details answer. However, in each of your solution you use "Hello" twice, which I'm trying to avoid. Also, your functions doesn't return "Hello" but "" if name is not provided. My question was more about how to generalize that to n-argument instead of reducing it to one.

Comment: @mb14 First of all, the examples I posted never return an empty string, they return `Nothing` in case there is no name. Secondly don't take the DRY principle to extremes, because in too simple cases it takes more code and obfuscates the otherwise evident solution. However I think I finally got what you were trying to ask so please see [my new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23843871/485115).

Comment: My question was obviously not clear enough. I updated my question. And yes your new answer is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid using a `Maybe` for the title and do:

```
greeting :: Bool-> Maybe String -> String
greeting title name = "Hello" ++ title' ++ (maybe "" id name)
  where title' = if title then "Mr" else ""
```

If you have a number of `Maybe`s you could use `mconcat` since `String` is a monoid:

```
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Maybe

greeting :: [Maybe String] -> String
greeting l = fromJust $ mconcat ((Just "Hello"):l)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your function is violating the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (Single responsibility principle). It is doing two things:

- prefixing the name with `Mr`
- rendering the greeting message

You can notice that the `Bool` and `String` (name) refer to the same "entity" (a person).

So let's define a person:

```
data Person 
    = Mister String
    | Person String
    deriving (Eq)
```

We can now create an instance of `show` that makes sense:

```
instance Show Person where
    show (Mister name) = "Mr. " ++ name
    show (Person name) = name
```

and finally we can reformulate your greeting function as:

```
greeting :: Maybe Person -> String
greeting (Just person) = "Hello, " ++ show person
greeting Nothing       = "Hello"
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c4588d019b7b201)

The code is simple, readable and just few lines longer (don't be afraid of writing code). The two actions (prefixing and greeting) are separated and everything is much simpler.

---

If you really have to, you can trivially create a function to generate a `Mister` or a `Person` based on a boolean value:

```
makePerson :: Bool -> String -> Person
makePerson True  = Mister
makePerson False = Person
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e024dbe595f51a7)

Comment: I agree about the SRP violation. However, this is kind of irrelevant here. I'm not trying to solve the exact problem in the question. It was just a "simple" example to clarify a more generic question. Moreover, your solution is using "Hello" twice, which is violationg the DRY principle (which I think is more important that SRP)

Comment: @mb14, the alternatives to overcome the 5 letters duplication much longer and reduce the simplicity of the solution. If the text was bigger I would definitely care about it and either create a `hello = ("Hello"++)` or [move the `case` to test the `Maybe` value](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac92d7d26279d221) onwards.

Comment: @jeffrey: My question maybe wasn't clear enough. I was more thinking of a complete template system that just adding 2 Maybe strings. If you can do it for 2, you can do it for n can't you ? See my update

Comment: @jeffrey : I downvoted because I felt refactoring a made-up example wasn't a constructive answer. See my initial comment.

Comment: @mb14, why didn't you downvote [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23838900/493122) as well?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post ... but it may be useful ...

in a pure "***functional***" way ...

```
greeting :: Maybe String -> String -> String
greeting Nothing name  = "Hello" ++ ", " ++ name
greeting (Just title) name  = "Hello" ++ ", " ++ title ++ " " ++ name ++ "!" 

how to call : 
-- greeting Nothing "John"
-- greeting Nothing "Charlotte"
-- greeting (Just "Mr.") "John"
-- greeting (Just "Miss.") "Charlotte"
```