# Convert value to sql select in Haskell

Tags: sql, haskell

I'm building a tool to query a database from an html form, and I defined a data type to capture the form values.  For example:

```
data BookSearchParams = BookSearchParams
{ Title       :: Maybe Text
  TitleSearchType :: SearchType
, Author      :: Maybe Text
, AuthorSearchType :: SearchType
}
```

The columns of the database are represented as fields in the data type and I'm using Maybe because the user may or may not enter that value in the form.  The SearchType fields are used to specify exact match, regex, or like.  I'd like to turn this into a sql select statement.

In an imperative language, I could just add each field to a string if the field was passed down:

```
if params.title:
    sql += params.title
```

In Haskell, I could do it with a lot of case statements to create a function with type:

```
bookSearchParamsToSql :: BookSearchParams -> Text
```

However, it would be a messy function.  How should this function be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23838630/376113) a couple of weeks ago, and the elegant answer was to use a `Writer` monad. (In fact, it's was exactly the same problem : building SQL query but I transformed it to a more general question).

```
import Control.Monad.Writer hiding (forM_)
import Data.Foldable

bookSearchSQL :: BookSearchParams -> Text
bookSearchSQL p = execWriter $ do
    tell "header of the query"
    forM_ (title p) $ \t -> "title = " ++ (show t)
    tell $ "type = " ++ (searchType p)
    forM_ (author p) $ \a -> "author = " ++ (show a)
```

(I haven't check it works or even compiles). The trick is to use `Data.Foldable.forM_` instead of the more traditional `Control.Monad.forM_`. The later take a list as argument but the foldable version takes any foldable, in our a case a `Maybe`.

Note, that in the lambda, `t` and `a` are not `Maybe` but `Text` and the lambda is only called is there is the `Maybe` is not `Nothing`.

Answer (score 3):

I would use Monoid to solve this problem.

```
import Data.Monoid (<>)

titleSQL, authorSQL :: BookSearchParams -> Text

bookSearchSQL p = titleSQL p <> authorSQL p
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concatenate all the `Text`s, you can use:

(Edit: forgot that `Text` are not `Strings` .. )

```hs
import Data.Monoid
params = ...
sql = [ s | Just s <- title params ] <>
      [ s | Just s <- author params ] <>
      ...
```

Or even something like

```hs
import Data.List (intersperse)
import Data.Text
import Data.Monoid
params = ...
sql = concat $ Data.List.intersperse " AND "
      [ [ "title='" <> escape s <> "'" | Just s <- title params ]
      , [ "author='" <> escape s <> "'" | Just s <- author params ]
      , ...
      ]
```

Of course, concatenating strings to build SQL queries is not very type safe (& potentially prone to injection attacks). I would instead give a look to the nice libraries we have which can assist in doing this. I can not recommend any one since I never used them :P, but they do exist and seem nice.