# Conditionally building a list

Tags: haskell, conditional-statements, idioms

I want to build a list of command line args from a bunch of other pre-defined variables in Haskell. As is the nature of many command line parameters, those are either present or not.

Is there a common idiom for conditionally building a list in Haskell? The if–then–else approach feels rather tedious:

```
import Control.Monad
join [ if opt1 then [a] else []
     , if opt2 then [b] else []
     , if opt3 then [c] else [] ]

-- gives me back [a, c] or something like that.
```

I have something like

```
onlyIf :: MonadPlus m => a -> Bool -> m a
onlyIf a p = if p then return a else mzero
```

or

```
mwhen :: Monoid a => Bool -> a -> a
mwhen p a = if p then a else mempty
```

in mind, which could then be used like

```
a `onlyIf` opt1 <>
b `onlyIf` opt2 <>
c `onlyIf` opt3
```

or

```
mwhen opt1 [a] <>
mwhen opt2 [b] <>
mwhen opt3 [c]
```

Hoogle is not really helpful here and of course, there may be a much better (/more common) way of doing this stuff.

Comment: What about `concatMap snd . filter fst` :)

Comment: @josejuan Did not think of that. Seems definitely more idiomatic than my own examples. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I like using `concat` with list comprehensions in that case:

```
concat
  [ [a | opt1]
  , [b | opt2]
  , [c | opt3]
  ]
```

`[a | opt1]` is the empty list if `opt1` is False, otherwise it is a singleton list containing only `a`.

You can also do it using `<$` and `guard`:

```
concat
  [ a <$ guard opt1
  , b <$ guard opt2
  , c <$ guard opt3
  ]
```

I don't think there exists a `onlyIf` function anywhere in base.

Comment: The guard trick is also useful together with `<*` when `a` is already a list. Guess, I don’t need a special function then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Writer` (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23838630/376113)) and use `when` instead of `Maybe`.
However using `Maybe` instead of condition,result can be better.

Comment: This doesn't even typecheck. `forM_ :: (Applicative f, Foldable t) => t a -> (a -> f x) -> f ()`, but in this case, `t a` would have to be `Bool`, which is impossible.